# OMDBAPI returns only 10 movies

Tags: javascript, omdbapi

I am trying to get all movies but the API only returns first 10 movies. Any help would be appreciated.

```
async getResults(page = 1) {
    const apiKey = '#######';
    const proxy = 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    try {

        while (page <= 5) {
            const res = await axios(`${proxy}http://www.omdbapi.com/? apikey=${apiKey}&s=${this.query}&type=movie&page=${page}`);
            this.result = res.data;
            this.page = page;
            page++;
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

OMDB API has pagination, which means it will return a set number of movie response data in each request. In this case it is returning 10 movies per request. You have to pass a query parameter `page=2` if you want to get the data for the second page, because page is not a required query parameter and defaults to 1.

check the official [OMDB docs](https://www.omdbapi.com/) for more info

Comment: I have wrapped my code in while loop and pass the page parameter and then incrementing the page by 1 on each request but still returns the first 10 movies. 
        

            while (page <= 5) {
                const res = await axios(`${proxy}http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKey}&s=${this.query}&type=movie&page=${page}`);
                this.result = res.data;
                this.page = page;
                page++;
            }

Comment: I don't see any page query parameter in the URL you provided in the question. Can you post the URL you are using and the surrounding loop in the post above ?

Comment: const res = await axios(`${proxy}http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKey}&s=${this.query}&type=movie&page=${page}`);

Comment: Please edit your question and update the API url. Also add the code block which calls the getResults function

Comment: I call the method in my controller.  try {

            //4-SEARCH FOR MOVIES  
            await state.search.getResults(page);

         

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }


    }